# Is there an axiom we can introduce that disallows Gödel sentences from being formed?

Tags: logic

If you're formulating a "set theory" and you allow sets to arbitrarily* self-reference, then you end up with Russell's paradox. (*I just learned today about Quine atoms. While they are not allowed in ZF, they allow for self-reference and don't have to allow for Russell's paradox, so perhaps self-reference is okay, sometimes.)

A solution is the axiom of foundation, which forbids such self-referential sets.

Now consider this:

> The Gödel sentence is designed to refer, indirectly, to itself. The sentence states that, when a particular sequence of steps is used to construct another sentence, that constructed sentence will not be provable in F. However, the sequence of steps is such that the constructed sentence turns out to be GF itself. In this way, the Gödel sentence GF indirectly states its own unprovability within F (Smith 2007, p. 135).

In the case of Russell's paradox, adding an axiom to disallow self-reference prevented the sentence from being formed.

Similarly, is there an axiom we can introduce that disallows Gödel sentences from being formed?

Comment: I do not think so. G's formula is a particular case of the more general phenomenon of [diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma): "Let $T$ be a first-order theory in the language of arithmetic and capable of representing all computable functions. Let $F$ be a formula in the language with one free variable, then: There is a sentence $\psi$ such that $\psi ↔ F(\ulcorner \psi \urcorner))$ is provable in $T$:"

Comment: Adding axioms doesn't help, if the existing axioms are already strong enough to self-reference. That is, adding axioms does not take away from that ability. You could of course try to take away axioms so they can't self-refer, but now even more sentences become unprovable.

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding that Russell's paradox arises from the possible existence of sets which contain themselves and that the axiom of foundation is a solution to this paradox. In fact, the paradox arises from unrestricted comprehension - foundation has nothing to do with it! There are set theories which are perfectly consistent (assuming ZFC is consistent), in which foundation fails in a big way: for example, look at [Aczel's anti-foundation axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aczel%27s_anti-foundation_axiom).

Answer (score 4):

No. *Adding* axioms can never prevent a construction from being carried out.

On a related note, you can *never* resolve a contradiction by adding more axioms. (in fact, if you have a contradiction in a theory, any new axioms you might consider adding are already theorems, by the principle of explosion!)

The key element to resolving Russell's paradox is *not* adding the axiom of foundation — it is *removing* the axiom of unrestricted comprehension, and replacing it with the more limited axiom of subsets.

Russell's paradox relies on having the axiom of unrestricted comprehension which implies that $\{ x \mid x \notin x \}$ is a set. If you add the axiom of foundation... the axiom of unrestricted comprehension *still* implies that $\{ x \mid x \notin x \}$ is a set.

But if you remove the axiom of unrestricted comprehension? In ZFC, there is no known proof that $\{ x \mid x \notin x \}$ is a set. And therefore, there is no known way to turn Russell's argument (which proves $\{ x \mid x \notin x \}$ is not a set) into a proof that ZFC leads to contradiction.

Comment: Well then I asked the wrong question.  Instead of asking if there was an axiom I could add, I should have asked if there are axiom(s) I could change.  Would it be acceptable to change my question to that?

Comment: @WordsLikeJared: Probably better to post a new question. You might want to read about [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) and [Robinson arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) before posing the new question.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  You could, for example, add a rule of inference that is not primitive recursive which theoretically could prevent the instantiation of the unary predicate in the diagonalization lemma from representing provability.  I'm not certain that is possible, but it doesn't seem obvious that it isn't.

Comment: @DanielV That's really no different than working in a non-computably-axiomatizable theory with the usual inference system, though.